# Edit jQuery to Change Color of Menu

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, css, jquery

My main landing page shows different images when different categories are hovered (using jQuery on my CMS page). I also want to tie into this and tell it to also change the color of the 'MENU' icon, too, depending on different image being shown (my 'menu' is a burger style created with the CSS below). How can I edit my jQuery to also call this function?

jQuery (in CMS page) for the image changing on hover:

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
(function(){
        var backgroundImages = [
            src="{{media url="landing.jpg"}}", // default background image link
            src="{{media url="/e-store.jpg"}}", // background image for category A
            src="{{media url="/e-store.jpg"}}", // background image for category B
            src="{{media url="/home-page.jpg"}}", // background image for category C
            src="{{media url="/press.jpg"}}", // background image for category D
            src="{{media url="/contact.jpg"}}", // background image for Contact
            src="{{media url="/etc.jpg"}}", // background image for Et Cetera
        ];

                function updateBg(position){
        jQuery('.main-container').css('background-image','url('+backgroundImages[position]+')');    
 jQuery('.skip-link.skip-nav span').css({ 
'color': '#3bcccc'  
 });  
    }

        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery('.nav-0').hover(function(){updateBg(1)},function(){updateBg(0)});
            jQuery('.nav-1').hover(function(){updateBg(2)},function(){updateBg(0)});
            jQuery('.nav-2').hover(function(){updateBg(3)},function(){updateBg(0)});
            jQuery('.nav-3').hover(function(){updateBg(4)},function(){updateBg(0)});
            jQuery('.nav-4').hover(function(){updateBg(5)},function(){updateBg(0)});
            jQuery('.nav-5').hover(function(){updateBg(6)},function(){updateBg(0)});
        });        
    })();
// ]]></script>
```

HTML for the 'MENU':

```
<div class="skip-links">
            <a href="#header-nav" class="skip-link skip-nav">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
                <span class="icon"></span>
                <span class="label">MENU</span>
            </a>
</div>
</div
```

CSS for the 'MENU':

```
.skip-link.skip-nav span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  width: 70%;
  border-radius: 9px;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out; 
  transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}

.skip-link.skip-nav span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
  background: #b0b0b0;
}

.skip-link.skip-nav span:nth-child(2),.skip-link.skip-nav span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 8px;
  background: #b0b0b0;
}


.skip-link.skip-nav span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 17px;
  background: #b0b0b0;
}

.skip-link.skip-nav.open span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 18px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
  background: #000;
    height: 2px;
}

.skip-link.skip-nav.open span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: #000;
height: 2px; 
}

.skip-link.skip-nav.open span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  background: #000;
  height: 2px;
}

.skip-link.skip-nav.open span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 18px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
  background: #000;
  height: 2px;
}  

.skip-link.skip-nav .label {
    margin-top: -10px;
    color: #b0b0b0;
    margin-left: -50px;
    font-weight: bold;
}


.skip-link.skip-nav.open .label {
    display: none;
}
```

UPDATE:

I have updated my jQuery above which is working, but how do I change it so that bg1 is white, bg2 is black, etc? I tried listing the color options, but it didn't seem to work.

UPDATE 2:

Here is my latest jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
(function($){
        var backgroundImages = [
            src='{{media url="landing.jpg"}}',
            src='{{media url="/e-store.jpg"}}',
            src='{{media url="/e-store.jpg"}}',
            src='{{media url="/home-page.jpg"}}',
            src='{{media url="/press.jpg"}}',
            src='{{media url="/contact.jpg"}}',
            src='{{media url="/etc.jpg"}}',
        ];

        function updateBg(position){
            $('.main-container').css('background-image','url('+backgroundImages[position]+')');
            if (position = 1) { var color = '#3bcccc' }
            else if (position = 0) { var color = '#333333' }
            else if (position = 2) { var color = '#0dd67e' }
            else if (position = 3) { var color = '#ff852b' }
            else { var color = '#030303' } // set a default color  
                $('.skip-link.skip-nav span').css({ 
                color: color
            });  
         }

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.nav-0').hover(function(){updateBg(1)},function(){updateBg(0)});
            $('.nav-1').hover(function(){updateBg(2)},function(){updateBg(0)});
            $('.nav-2').hover(function(){updateBg(3)},function(){updateBg(0)});
            $('.nav-3').hover(function(){updateBg(4)},function(){updateBg(0)});
            $('.nav-4').hover(function(){updateBg(5)},function(){updateBg(0)});
            $('.nav-5').hover(function(){updateBg(6)},function(){updateBg(0)});
        });        
})(jQuery);
// ]]></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use your current function updateBg to add more CSS selectors like this:

```
jQuery('.main-container').css({ 
    'background-image': 'url(+backgroundImages[position]+)',
    'color': 'red'    
});
```

Alternatively, you could add to your existing function after the code above:

```
jQuery('.skip-link').css({ 
    'color': 'red'    
});
```

Or, create a new function and add it to your hover event listener:

```
jQuery('.nav-0').hover(function(){updateBg(1)},function(){updateBg(0)},function(){updateColor(1)});

function updateColor(position){
    jQuery('.skip-link').css({ 
        'color': 'red'    
    });
}
```

**UPDATE**: Okay, so you have the following code which I believe is working for you, except you want to use different colors for different "positions":

```
function updateBg(position){
    jQuery('.main-container').css('background-image','url('+backgroundImages[position]+')');    
    jQuery('.skip-link.skip-nav span').css({ 'color': '#3bcccc' });  
}
```

So, the easiest way (although maybe the longest) would be like this:

```
function updateBg(position){
    jQuery('.main-container').css('background-image','url('+backgroundImages[position]+')');
    if (position === 1) { var color = '#3bcccc' }
    if (position === 0) { var color = '#333333' }
        else { var color = '#030303' } // set a default color   
    jQuery('.skip-link.skip-nav span').css({ 'color': color });  
}
```

UPDATE:

Your full code with syntax errors corrected:

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
(function($){
        var backgroundImages = [
            src='{{media url="landing.jpg"}}',
            src='{{media url="/e-store.jpg"}}',
            src='{{media url="/e-store.jpg"}}',
            src='{{media url="/home-page.jpg"}}',
            src='{{media url="/press.jpg"}}',
            src='{{media url="/contact.jpg"}}',
            src='{{media url="/etc.jpg"}}',
        ];

        function updateBg(position){
            $('.main-container').css('background-image','url('+backgroundImages[position]+')');
            if (position === 1) { var color = '#3bcccc' }
            else if (position === 0) { var color = '#333333' }
            else { var color = '#030303' } // set a default color  
                $('.skip-link.skip-nav span').css({ 
                color: color
            });  
         }

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.nav-0').hover(function(){updateBg(1)},function(){updateBg(0)});
            $('.nav-1').hover(function(){updateBg(2)},function(){updateBg(0)});
            $('.nav-2').hover(function(){updateBg(3)},function(){updateBg(0)});
            $('.nav-3').hover(function(){updateBg(4)},function(){updateBg(0)});
            $('.nav-4').hover(function(){updateBg(5)},function(){updateBg(0)});
            $('.nav-5').hover(function(){updateBg(6)},function(){updateBg(0)});
        });        
})(jQuery);
// ]]></script>
```

Comment: firstly, thank you!! I have been struggling with this for almost a week now and this is by far the closest i've got!! Completely appreciate your help. The middle option seemed to work for me, however how do I give other color options? I.e. Bg1 is black, bg2 is white? I will update my code above...

Comment: also, it might be worth noting that i tried to list the color options similar to the image options, but this didn't work. I'm so close yet can't figure this little bit out... :)

Comment: any help you can give is extremely appreciated - sorry to bombard, I have a deadline and need to get this finished tonight. I just don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Just put those in your functions. I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: Thank you! I copied the function exactly as you had it above but it just seems to pick up the default color...

Comment: Try `console.log(position)` then check (like in chrome) your console to see what the value of 'position' is. Maybe try `position == 1`

Comment: Give me a few minutes to look at your code in an editor. I think you have some syntax errors.

Comment: Looking into that now. I tried position = 0 and what's strange is it's now picking up whatever the position is of the last item listed. i.e. position = 3 is now the color being picked up. When I added position = 4 it then picked that one up for them all.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Honestly appreciate all your help!!!!

Comment: Ok, answer has been updated with your code at the bottom.

Comment: Thank you, it's still doing either the default with position === 1 or position == 1, if I do position = 1 it picks up the very last color defined. Just trying to see my 'position' now

Comment: Am having difficulty working out my position

Comment: Sorry, I missed an `else`. Recopy that portion and you should be good. (I updated)

Comment: It's still doing the same thing. Position === 1 or position == 1 picks up the default, position = 1 picks up the last color listed. Sorry... I'm sure you're getting just as frustrated with this now as I have been

Comment: I've posted an update to my question with the jQuery that I now have.

Comment: The problem with it now is the same as the problem I gave you with the missing `else` statement. Basically what is happening with your `if` statements is at the end it is hitting else despite it being true in the previous `if`. You need to add `else` to the `if`s (not the first one) like `else if`

Comment: Okay, now it picks up the color of the very first 'position = 1' and only that. If I have position == 1 or position === 1 it goes back to the default again. Will update my code again. So sorry, really don't mean to be so difficult.

Comment: In `PHP` the operator `=` sets a value. So `$this_variable = 'cat'` will make the variable equal 'cat'. On the other hand, this expression `==` means 'IS this equal'? So, the first is a statement, the second a question. So when you're doing `if ($var = 'val')` you're just setting `$var` to `val`

Comment: Thank you. One more question; if I also want to tell it to change the properties of 'background' (in addition to 'color) how would I add this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24390/discussion-between-tim-hallman-and-itsk2015).